# dataLabels for bar chart in Highcharts not displaying for null values in 3.0.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been using the following code to set dataLabels for bar charts in Highcharts...

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                if (this.y==null) {
                    return '<i>(Suppressed)</i>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to show the user when a value has been hidden for privacy reasons.

In previous versions of Highcharts, the label would show up for the null values as I desired. In version 3.0.8, I do not get any dataLabels for the null vales.

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly bug, reported here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2899

Workaround: use renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian points out, this is in fact a bug. However, there is an easy fix... In highcharts.src.js, simply change the call to the pick function for getting plotX and plotY in Series.prototype.alignDataLabel (lines 16132 and 16133) to:

```
plotX = pick(point.plotX, 0),
plotY = pick(point.plotY, 0),
```

rather than

```
plotX = pick(point.plotX, -999),
plotY = pick(point.plotY, -999),
```

Hope this ends up being helpful to somebody...