# Column Chart Show datalabel for null values - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

This question is a possible duplicate of
[Show N/A in datalabels, when value is null - Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830042/show-n-a-in-datalabels-when-value-is-null-highcharts)

and 
[dataLabels for bar chart in Highcharts not displaying for null values in 3.0.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963501/datalabels-for-bar-chart-in-highcharts-not-displaying-for-null-values-in-3-0-8)

but workarounds suggested have stopped working in version 5.0.7 of highcharts.

```
formatter: function () {
    if (this.y == null) {
        var chart = this.series.chart,
            categoryWidth = chart.plotWidth / chart.xAxis[0].categories.length,
            offset = (this.point.x) * categoryWidth + categoryWidth / 2,
            text = chart.renderer.text('N/A', -999, -999).add();

        text.attr({
            x: chart.plotLeft + offset - text.getBBox().width / 2, //center label
            y: chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 8 // padding
        });

    } else {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be still open on github: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2899

http://jsfiddle.net/90amxpc1/4/

Is there a possible workaround to show something like "N/A" using formatter function or chart.renderer method for null values in column charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In new version of Highcharts formatter is not called for null points anymore.

A hacky way to make your code works as it worked before is to wrap `drawDataLabels()` method and temporary assign some value to null points, e.g. 0, and in formatter check if `point.isNull` is true.

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function (p) {
  this.points.forEach(point => {
    if (point.y === null) {
      point.y = 0;
    }
  });

  p.call(this);

  this.points.forEach(point => {
    if (point.isNull) {
      point.y = null;
    }
  });
});
```

In data labels config:

```
 dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.point.isNull) {
                    var chart = this.series.chart,
                        categoryWidth = chart.plotWidth / chart.xAxis[0].categories.length,
                        offset = (this.point.x) * categoryWidth + categoryWidth / 2,
                        text = chart.renderer.text('N/A', -999, -999).add();

                    text.attr({
                        x: chart.plotLeft + offset - text.getBBox().width / 2, //center label
                        y: chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 8 // padding
                    });

                    return false;
                } else {
                    return this.y;
                }
            },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xnxpwt67/

It works, but it is not an elegant and efficient solution. Much better would be drawing labels for nulls, e.g. on load event.

```
    chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const categoryWidth = this.plotWidth / this.xAxis[0].categories.length;

      this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
        if (point.y === null) {
          const offset = point.x * categoryWidth + categoryWidth / 2;
          const text = this.renderer.text('N/A', -999, -999).add();

          text.attr({
            x: this.plotLeft + offset - text.getBBox().width / 2,
            y: this.plotTop + this.plotHeight - 8
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xnxpwt67/1/

Comment: Thank you. It works well, I was able to generalize it to multiple series: https://jsfiddle.net/saad749/ss36jep0/1/   .. but the positioning of the label becomes more difficult. This method requires more pre-processing for null values but no need to manually position the labels.    
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2899#issuecomment-281036396